# How to check if value in array is not NULL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So I am parsing a twitter timeline. There is a field called "following" in the JSON response. It should be true or false.

But sometimes the field is missing.

When I do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[timeline objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"following"]);
```

This is the output:

```
1
1
0
0
1
<null>
1
1
```

So how to check for those  values?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NSArray` and other collections can't take `nil` as a value, since nil is the "sentinel value" for when the collection ends. You can find if an object is null by using:

```
if (myObject == [NSNull null]) {
    // do something because the object is null
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the field is missing, NSDictionary -objectForKey: will return a nil pointer. You can test for a nil pointer like this:

```
NSNumber *following = [[[timeline objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"following"];

if (following)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", following);
}
else
{
    // handle no following field
    NSLog(@"No following field");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not the timeline element that's null.  It's either the "user" dictionary or the "following" object that's null.  I recommend creating a user model class to encapsulate some of the json/dictionary messiness.  In fact, I bet you could find an open source Twitter API for iOS.

Either way, your code would be more readable as something like:

```
TwitterResponse *response = [[TwitterResponse alloc] initWithDictionary:[timeline objectAtIndex:i]];
NSLog(@"%@", response.user.following);
```

`TwitterResponse` above would implement a readonly property `TwitterUser *user` which would in turn implement `NSNumber *following`.  Using `NSNumber` because it would allow null values (empty strings in the JSON response).

Hope this helps get you on the right track.  Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

for checking array contain null value use  this code.

```
if ([array objectAtIndex:0] == [NSNull null])
{
//do something
}
else
{
}
```